# How to run react and activate python virtualenv with concurrently npm package or with one command

Tags: python, npm, virtualenv, npm-scripts, concurrently

I am trying to create a npm run script that can start react app and then activate python virtual env to run flask server.

scripts in package.json:

```json
{
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "both": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"cd ../backend && "env/scripts/activate\" && py src/app.py\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
}
```

above I am using `concurrently`. But executing the `both` script run react and give following error:

```
[1] 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[1] operable program or batch file.
[1] cd ../backend && env/scripts/activate && py src/app.py exited with code 1
[0] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.137.1/
[0] i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
[0] i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\Work\movielust\frontend\public
[0] i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
[0] Starting the development server...
```

My dir structure is:

```
main
|___frontend
|   |___package.json
|___backend
|   |___env
|   |___src
|       |___app.py
```

is there any workaround for this or this not really possible or is threre any other way to achieve running both react and flask in one go?

Comment: How did you create your virtual environment? Via virtualenv?

Comment: @Virtuoz yes with virtualenv

Comment: Did you try `. env\scripts\activate` ?

Comment: just tried, it gave `'.env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` @Virtuoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- run your virtual environment
- don't try to change path or activate virtualenv from within the scripts in package.json

```js
"scripts":
  "flask-dev": "pip install -r requirements.txt && python -m flask --app api/index run -p 5328 --reload",
      "next-dev": "next dev",
      "dev": "concurrently \"pnpm run next-dev\" \"pnpm run flask-dev\"",
```

then run **npm run dev** which will pick up the environment and packages from it...